# add select options to id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to give same select options multiple times with different names.
check my code and help me!

this code is working when i am using only single id.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
      

    //select options for spending amount
    select = document.querySelectorAll("#amount0, #amount1, #amount2, #amount3, #amount4");
    var opt1 = document.createElement('option');
    opt1.value = 35;
    opt1.innerHTML = 35;
    select.appendChild(opt1);

    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = 50;
    opt.value = 50;
    select.appendChild(opt);

    //loop for 100 to 1000
    for (var i = 1; i<=10; i++){
      var opt = document.createElement('option');
      var x = 100;
      x = x*i;
      opt.value = x;
      opt.innerHTML = x;
      select.appendChild(opt);
    }

  });
```

```html
<td><select id="amount0" name="amount_monday" class="form-control input-sm"></select></td>
<td><select id="amount1" name="amount_tuesday" class="form-control input-sm"></select></td>
<td><select id="amount2" name="amount_wednesday" class="form-control input-sm"></select></td>
<td><select id="amount3" name="amount_friday" class="form-control input-sm"></select></td>
<td><select id="amount4" name="amount_sunday" class="form-control input-sm"></select></td>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: document.querySelectorAll("#amount0, #amount1, #amount2, #amount3, #amount4"); is returning array of NodeList, we cann't call appendChild() on this NodeList, this will result error.
So, iterate the NodeList Okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
      

    //select options for spending amount
    select = document.querySelectorAll("#amount0, #amount1, #amount2, #amount3, #amount4");
  var selCount = select.length;
  
 for(var sC=0; sC<selCount; sC++){
   var opt1 = document.createElement('option');
    opt1.value = 35;
    opt1.innerHTML = 35;
    select[sC].appendChild(opt1);

    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = 50;
    opt.value = 50;
    select[sC].appendChild(opt);

    //loop for 100 to 1000
    for (var i = 1; i<=10; i++){
      var opt = document.createElement('option');
      var x = 100;
      x = x*i;
      opt.value = x;
      opt.innerHTML = x;
      select[sC].appendChild(opt);
    }
  }
    

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<td><select id="amount0" name="amount_monday" class="form-control input-sm"></select></td>
<td><select id="amount1" name="amount_tuesday" class="form-control input-sm"></select></td>
<td><select id="amount2" name="amount_wednesday" class="form-control input-sm"></select></td>
<td><select id="amount3" name="amount_friday" class="form-control input-sm"></select></td>
<td><select id="amount4" name="amount_sunday" class="form-control input-sm"></select></td>
```

Hope you got, what to change.

Comment: it's work fine, Actually i got same thought but i didnt implement in proper way thanks.

Comment: can i call all id's by single reference ? why becoz i have 35 select options. can u help me?

Comment: We can achieve it, by using class name.So add a specific class(mySelect) to all select boxes and query those. document.querySelectorAll("select.mySelect") this will fetch all select boxes which are having mySelect class.
Hope it'll solve your problem, If not ask me for more.

Comment: <input type="radio" class="mySelect" id="1">
<input type="radio" class="mySelect" id="2">
<input type="radio" class="mySelect" id="3">
like this?

Comment: select.mySelect is working nicely, 
now i am going to solve disable and enable select option column, can u guide me?
i updated the code


you can check my work at
https://jsfiddle.net/setti565/8s51b0eq/2/

Comment: I hope you are looking for this, check out this link https://jsfiddle.net/v7b5es71/

Comment: once again you done great work but at initially all select boxes should be disable, when user click on the radio button the related select box should enable.

Comment: Okay,
For that we need to write disabled='disabled' to all select boxes.And in your fiddle you are using same id multiple time, but according to rules, In one html DOM element we should not duplicate ID. Because that will make retrieving the elements will goes flaw. So try to use UNIQUE ID for each element.

Comment: sure, i will give unique id. i have done disabled="true" it is working fine.

Comment: if(index==1){
    selectBoxes[0].disabled=false;
  }else if(index==3){
    selectBoxes[1].disabled=false;
  }else if(index==5){
    selectBoxes[2].disabled=false;
  }


can u give small explaination ?

Comment: Okay, I updated the fiddle with all the explanation, check out this https://jsfiddle.net/v7b5es71/1/



If know debugging enable debugger and un comment the console.log(), and see the console Okay.

Comment: can you check your jsfiddle, if we click reselect any other radio button, the current selectbox is not reseting. it is showing selected value only

Comment: Oh...you want not only disabling the select box and also reset the value.Check out now https://jsfiddle.net/v7b5es71/2/       added one line 'selectBox.options[0].selected=true;'

Answer (score 1):

Can you elaborate more i can't seem to understand what you want by the way why are you using

```
 querySelectorAll
```

when you can simply re-order you html as follows :

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <td><select id="amount0" name="amount_monday" class="amountselect form-control input-sm">     </select></td>
 <td><select id="amount1" name="amount_tuesday" class="amountselect form-control input-sm"> 


$(function(){
    //all the selects are here
    var selects = $("select.amountselect")
 });
```

Comment: hi, i got solution but i saw your code,
var selects = $("select.amountselect")
what is the amountselect here?

can i call all id's by single reference ?

Comment: check out the class attribute I added amountselect as a for all selects now you can select the elements using this class selector.

Answer (score 0):

```
var opt = ""
for (var i = 1; i<=10; i++){
      var x=100;
      var opt = "<option value='"+x*i+"'>"+x*i+"</option>";
    }

$("#amount0, #amount1, #amount2, #amount3, #amount4").html(opt);
// or $(".form-control").html(opt);
```

Will do the thing.

Answer (score 0):

You should mention the index of select array. Also always load jquery library file at the top.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
      

    //select options for spending amount
    select = document.querySelectorAll("#amount0, #amount1, #amount2, #amount3, #amount4");
    var opt1 = document.createElement('option');
    opt1.value = 35;
    opt1.innerHTML = 35;
    select[0].appendChild(opt1);

    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = 50;
    opt.value = 50;
    select[0].appendChild(opt);

    //loop for 100 to 1000
    for (var i = 1; i<=10; i++){
      var opt = document.createElement('option');
      var x = 100;
      x = x*i;
      opt.value = x;
      opt.innerHTML = x;
      select[0].appendChild(opt);
    }

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```